# Password protect database

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core 1.0 to manage an SQLite database in a C# desktop application. How to password-protect the database?

I know how using .NET class System.Data.SQLite, but how to do it using  Entity Framework Core 1.0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a password protected database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903863/how-to-create-a-password-protected-database)

Answer (score 11):

With  EntityFramework Core 2.0 (EFCore 2.0), It is possible to use Encrypted SQLite database.

Steps for using SQLite Encrypted (SQLCiher) database with EFCore

1. Add the reference of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design in your
   project.
2. Add the reference of
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core. This is really important
   step. Don't add the reference of
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite. Otherwise it will not work.
3. Add the reference of SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher. For encryption
   it is required. Add the following line ExcludeAssets="All" is
   important otherwise it will not work. For details refer to following link
   http://www.bricelam.net/2016/06/13/sqlite-encryption.html

   Download the working example from [Github](https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/SQLiteEncryptionUsingEFCore)

Comment: I have xamarin forms application and i try your method, but it doesn't work. I get this error when creating database: SQLite Error 1: 'cannot rollback - no transaction is active'. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

EF Core uses Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, which does not currently support encryption out-of-box. See https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/184. You could add encryption yourself using SQLite extensions.