# Cannot provide password in connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

In SQLite with Entity Framework I create the database with :

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{   
    // DbSets, OnModelCreating(), etc.

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=c:\\test.db");
    }
}

//this is in my test method
 using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    db.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

It works; database gets created. But I want to encrypt the database by providing a password in connection string:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=c:\\test.db;Password=mypassword");
```

From `EnsureCreated` I get :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
> Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'password'.

How can I encrypt that SQLite database?

Comment: where is your password stored right now, if it is in the web.config then you can use aspnet_regiis -pef to encrypt the config file

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060250/protect-sqlite-database-used-by-entityframework-core-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a password protected database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903863/how-to-create-a-password-protected-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this answer [Protect SQLite database used by EntityFramework Core Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35095428/5233410)

> EF Core uses Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, which does not currently support
>   encryption out-of-box. See
>   https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/184. You could
>   add encryption yourself using SQLite extensions.

At the GitHub link provided there were other links to an alternative at

[Encryption in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](http://www.bricelam.net/2016/06/13/sqlite-encryption.html)

Comment: That also throws exception "Keyword not supported: 'version'."

Answer (score 7):

The "pure", open source sqlite3.dll does not support encryption. There are other implementations, including licenced and unlicensed. 
For my solution I have used [rindeal/SQLite3-Encryption project from GitHub](https://github.com/rindeal/SQLite3-Encryption)

My solution:

1. Download compiled binaries
2. Copy sqlite3.dll to BIN folder

   - add the DLL to project in Visual Studio
   - set Copy to Output Directory - Copy always
3. Use this code in context's constructor:

   ```
   string password;
   var connection = Database.GetDbConnection();
   connection.Open();
   using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
       command.CommandText = $"PRAGMA key='{password}';";
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I've used that implementation that Tschareck posted:

```
 private const string Password = "1234";
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var conn = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=test.db;");
            conn.Open();

            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = $"PRAGMA key = '{Password}';";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(conn);
        }
```

and managed to put the password to my solution, and solution works fine, but I have another problem - I cannot open database (I'm using DB Browser for SQL Lite) using that password (when I click "Ok" Password gets deleted and nothing happens):

[printScreen DB Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lli4G.png)

Comment: DB browser cannot open encrypted file. Only way to open it is to unlock database first "manually": 
copy sqlite3.exe into the folder with database, 
run command line tool
run command: sqlite3 -key YourKey DBname.db
(where YourKey  is key you have used for encription, and DBname is name of your database)
run command: .rekey YourKey "" ""

Comment: You can use this other SQLite Browser "SQLite2009 Pro Enterprise Manager" http://sqlite2009pro.azurewebsites.net/ If the database is protected by password the browser ask you the password