# Add password to Sqlite file in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I have a Xamarin form application that creates a Sqlite database.

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` is used to create the database. I want to add a password to the file. I searched the internet, but unfortunately I can't find any obvious way. On StackOverflow, there are some questions that are similar to my question, however, the platform is not Xamarin Forms.

Here are the questions:

- [Password protected SQLite with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903863/password-protected-sqlite-with-entity-framework-core)
- [Cannot provide password in Connection String for SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860933/cannot-provide-password-in-connection-string-for-sqlite)

This is my code for creating the database:

```
public class DoctorDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
        private readonly string DatabasePath;

        public virtual DbSet<OperationsNames> OperationsNames { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CommonChiefComplaint> CommonChiefComplaint { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CommonDiagnosis> CommonDiagnosis { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CommonLabTests> CommonLabTests { get; set; }

        public DoctorDatabaseContext(string DatabasePath)
        {
            FixedDatabasePath.Path = this.DatabasePath = DatabasePath;

            Database.EnsureCreated();    
        }    

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={DatabasePath}");    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a post on [Encryption in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](http://www.bricelam.net/2016/06/13/sqlite-encryption.html). You can leverage it in EF Core by passing in an open connection to `UseSqlite`.

Instead of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`, use these packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core
- SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher

---

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    // TODO: Dispose with DbContext
    _connection = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
    _connection.Open();

    // TODO: Avoid SQL injection (see post)
    var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "PRAGMA key = '" + _password + "'";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    options.UseSqlite(_connection);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there are two points that I don't understand. First, you are using variable `_connection` and in the next line you use `connection`, is that two different variables? The second point is that I can't see where the database file will saved.

Comment: @AhmedShamel For your first question i am pretty sure that its a spelling error. For the second question you can use the second constructor of [SqliteConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteconnection.-ctor?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0#Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteConnection__ctor_System_String_)

Comment: Sorry, this certainly wasn't a complete code listing, just something to get you started. Variables that start with `_` above should be fields on the class.

Comment: @bricelam Again, thanks for the answer. It solve my problem. But I don't know how the package `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher` works? I just install it and don't use it in my code.

Comment: By default (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`) bundle_green (a vanilla SQLite build) is used. `Microsoft..Sqlite.Core` lets you bring your own bundle. bundle_sqlcipher is a build of SQLite called SQLCipher which supports encryption. It all works by [pure, battery-powered magic](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/blob/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/Utilities/BundleInitializer.cs).

Comment: @bricelam Thanks again. I now have one problem. After applying your solution, the database type become `SQLCipher ` and I need the database type to be `System.Data.SQLite` because I have a Windows application that produce `System.Data.SQLite` database and I want the two applications to produce the same database. is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so. System.Data.SQLite encryption is a very different implementation than SQLCipher. The algorithms used by System.Data.SQLite are Windows-only (and unsupported).

Comment: @bricelam is this still valid for EF? I have tried with above but my ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 and I am not seeing any difference

Comment: It should still work. We also added the [`Password`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings#password) connection string keyword  that you can use instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add password protection for sqlite db out of the box, there is a whole explanation [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59832/how-to-set-password-to-sqlite-db-in-xamain) regarding the reason in more details.

however, there is a nice solution shown on this [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91691/how-to-use-sqlite-with-password-protection-on-access) using [SQL Chiper](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) to encrypt you DB per page, if you are willing to invest the money.

If you want to encrypt and decrypt your entire db file on demand use [PCLCrypto](https://github.com/AArnott/PCLCrypto).

But as you noticed, the only way for you to achieve this kind of protection is via encryption of your db file, you won't be able to set password.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question but a suggestion.
You can use a library called Akavache to store data.

There are four storage locations:
 - BlobCache.LocalMachine - Device storage 
 - BlobCache.UserAccount - User
   settings. Some systems backup this data to the cloud.
 - BlobCache.Secure - For saving sensitive data - like credentials.(encrypted)
 - BlobCache.InMemory - A database, kept in memory. The data
   is stored for the lifetime of the app.

Hope that helps